# how to set up Django filter_horizontal filtering in admin page?

Tags: python, django, select, filter, model

I have been reading quite a few threads and postings about this build in `filter_horizontal` provided by django.

Somehow I tried and just wouldn't get it to work.
Can someone please give me a hand? Also, I am not trying to add this into any public view.  I am trying to add it into an admin page.

I have these 3 models: group, file, student

student to file is a many to many field.

Let's say this works as....
students signs up, I as admin will put the student into a certain group.
Let's say Group *Vacation*.
I will also upload a file from admin page.
Then what I really want here is...I need to assign the file created into a group.
BUT when I do the assign file to a group, it uses a dropdown like the image below.

[image]

Let's say if I have 100 files, 100 groups or even more.
It'll be annoying to go through the dropdown though.

So I want to try doing something such as

or at least something close to it. It has a filter, and I can see the selections in multiple select options.

[image]

Also, as seen in the image above.  There's file and group which are the two selections I need, but in my class `AssignFileToGroup` `File` and `Group` are Foreign keys though.

Been searching around and saw the `filter_horizontal` but, I tried it a few times adding it into the `File > admin.py` but no matter how I try it and reading other documentations, I still can't make it work, also `filter_horizontal` is for manytomanyfields.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks in advance, what's below is my code

let's say I have this in my File **model.py**

```
class File(Model):
    file_name = CharField(max_length=256)
    file = FileField(upload_to=FILE_UPLOAD_ROOT)
    creator = ForeignKey(Tutor,
                         on_delete=CASCADE,
                         related_name="%(class)ss",
                         related_query_name="%(class)s")
    groups = ManyToManyField(Group,
                             related_name="%(class)ss",
                             related_query_name="%(class)s",
                             through='AssignFileToGroup',
                             through_fields=('file', 'group'))


class AssignFileToGroup(Model):
    file = ForeignKey(File,
                      on_delete=CASCADE,
                      related_name="%(class)ss",
                      related_query_name="%(class)s")
    group = ForeignKey(Group,
                       on_delete=CASCADE,
                       related_name="%(class)ss",
                       related_query_name="%(class)s")
    assignment_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    student_views = ManyToManyField(Student,
                                    related_name="%(class)ss",
                                    related_query_name="%(class)s",
                                    through='StudentRecord',
                                    through_fields=('assign_file',
                                                    'from_student'))

class StudentRecord(Model):
    assign_file = ForeignKey(AssignFileToGroup,
                                    on_delete=CASCADE,
                                    related_name="%(class)ss",
                                    related_query_name="%(class)s")
    from_student = ForeignKey(Student,
                              on_delete=CASCADE,
                              related_name="%(class)ss",
                              related_query_name="%(class)s")
```

In my Group **model.py**

```
class Group(Model):
    creator = ForeignKey(Tutor,
                         on_delete=CASCADE,
                         related_name="%(class)ss",
                         related_query_name="%(class)s")
    group_name = CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
```

Comment: See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models): _When you specify an intermediary model using the through argument to a ManyToManyField, the admin will not display a widget by default. This is because each instance of that intermediary model requires more information than could be displayed in a single widget, and the layout required for multiple widgets will vary depending on the intermediate model._

Comment: @Selcuk I just scan through the documents, but it didn't mention anything about filter though. I will give it a try in a bit for the multiselection part. Thanks for the info.  If this works for me, how can I add in the filter part?

Comment: Re-read the excerpt from the documentation in my comment. The "widget" refers to the horizontal_filter. You can't directly use it in your case because you have extra fields in your through model (such as `assignment_date` and `student_views`). How are you planning to include those when you make a multiple choice?

Comment: @Selcuk those two doesn't need to be included though.  As my first picture shows, that's the only two fields shown in the admin page and those two are also what I needed to make them into filterable and select